# How to send text to the amount field within the Angular Page using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to enter Amount value as '123450'(For ex.) in the below url.

Steps -

1. Go to URL [link](https://iecouat.kotakcherry.com/ieco/#/home)
2. Click on 'Deposits' on the top menu bar
3. Click 'Fixed Deposit >'
4. You'll see the Fixed Deposit page with Amount field as 10,000 by default.

I want to change that field and enter any other amount.

Xpath I identified -

```
//This works when the site loaded for the first time with 10,000 as the default value
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='ieco-blue-underline']/span/b")
WebElement amountField;

//The XPath changes when we enter Amount as '500' <Tab out>..the XPath becomes as per below-
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='ieco-blue-underline']/input")
WebElement amountField;
```

Do I need to use 1st xpath when entering for the first time..and then use 2nd xpath when I enter values like 500,1000 ?

I have tried 3 ways but none of them worked so far -

```
public static void sendKeysWithWait(WebElement element, String text){
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

1. element.click();
   element.clear();
   //element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
   element.sendKeys(text);
   //Pressing Tab key
   element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);*/
2. Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   actions.moveToElement(element);
   actions.click();
   actions.sendKeys(text);
   actions.build().perform();
   //Pressing Tab key
   element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
3. element.click();
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='2222';", element);

In each of these ways, Click is working..but sendkeys not working.
I'm using chromedriver for execution, and Selenium version 3.141.59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the character sequence **123450** to the *Amount* field within the [webpage](https://iecouat.kotakcherry.com/ieco/#/deposit/fixed-deposit), as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.ieco-invest-rb20 span.ng-star-inserted>b"))).click();
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='investedAmt']")));
  element.clear();
  element.sendKeys("123450");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'ieco-invest-rb20')]//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']/b"))).click();
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='investedAmt']")));
  element.clear();
  element.sendKeys("123450");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: investedAmt]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, your first xpath is wrong as the event is bound to that div.

You xpath should be

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='ieco-blue-underline']")
WebElement amountField;
```

Then try to use the first method of using click.
Hope this works